# Excel pivot table filter links to cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a novice VBA user and already posted on this issue, but had to re-do some tables in my workbook and the initial question ended up being inaccurate, hence trying again.

I have modified a code found online to work with my workbook which:

- links a cell to a my pivot table filter;
- updates the filter and refreshes pivot table once the cell has been updated or activated;

Works great. The challange is that there are 2 pivot tables on the same worksheet and I'd need to filter 2 tables at the same time. Also the filter data is different, so the filter should be linked to different cells, although they do change at the same time.

The code I was using is below. Now there is `PivotTable1` and `PivotTable2`; entry to cell `H6` is linked to the 1st table and `H7` to the other table. Got a little overwhelmed at this point, but this should be possible within the same code, right?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
'H6 or H7 is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("H6:H7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Category")
NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H6").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this working for one table? Have you expanded it to filter the second table? It's easily possible with the code you have.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be amended as follows...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
    'H6 or H7 is touched
    If Intersect(Target, Range("H6:H7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Set the Variables to be used
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField
    Dim vPivotTableNames As Variant
    Dim vNewCats As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Assign the pivottable names to a variable
    vPivotTableNames = Array("PivotTable1", "PivotTable2")

    'Assign the new categories to a variable
    vNewCats = Range("H6:H7").Value

    'Update the pivotables
    For i = LBound(vPivotTableNames) To UBound(vPivotTableNames)
        Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(vPivotTableNames(i))
        Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Category")
        With Field
            .ClearAllFilters
            .CurrentPage = vNewCats(i + 1, 1)
        End With
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next i

End Sub
```

Although, the For/Next loop can be re-written as follows...

```
'Update the pivotables
For i = LBound(vPivotTableNames) To UBound(vPivotTableNames)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(vPivotTableNames(i))
        With .PivotFields("Category")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .CurrentPage = vNewCats(i + 1, 1)
        End With
        .RefreshTable
    End With
Next i
```